# Make Grid-Item-List with special order. (e.g. with flex-box, etc..)

Tags: html, list, css, grid, flexbox

i'm trying to make a special grid-list, but i cant find a solution that works (on desktop and mobile), maybe someone of you know a solution or has a tip for me.

I need a list (left image) with an special layout, this is not the problem by adding multiple nested grids, but(!) i would like to add a class on the list-element (wrapper) and wanna have another grid layout (right image). I tried to work with flexbox, i think there is no css3 solution and i have to do it with javascript - but before i take the js-solution, i wanna ask u, maybe you know a better one.

for better understanding i added an image to illustrate what i mean.

[image]

Comment: You should always add some code of your current solution, it helps the people trying to help you

Answer (score 0):

This is one posibility, playing with margins

```css
.list {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 150px;
  border: solid 1px green;
  margin: 5px;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px blue;
}

.list:not(.first) .jumbo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: -100px;
}

.list:not(.first) .jumbo + .item {
  margin-right: 100px;  
}
.first .item:first-child {
  width: 150px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item jumbo">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>

<div class="list first">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item jumbo">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```